# Erro ao inserir na tabela: "missing FROM-clause entry for table..."

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

**Eu tenho três tabelas:**

```
CREATE TABLE Bebidas(
id SERIAL primary key,
nome varchar(40) NOT NULL,
preco_bebidas decimal(5,2) check (preco_bebidas > 0.00),
    qntd int);

CREATE TABLE Shots(
    id SERIAL primary key,
    nome varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    preco_shots decimal(5,2) CHECK (preco_shots > 0.00));

CREATE TABLE Vendas(
    id SERIAL,
    id_bebidas int references Bebidas(id),
    id_shots int references Shots(id),
    qntd int CHECK (qntd >= 0),
    total decimal(5,2),
    data date);
```

Eu criei uma função *VENDER* para quando o adm vender uma bebida ou shot automaticamente ser inserida na tabela vendas. Porém, o PostgreSQL dá o seguinte erro:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "preco_bebidas"
>   LINE 1: ...T INTO vendas VALUES(default, variavel, null, $3, preco_bebi... (erro em preco...)
>
> QUERY:  INSERT INTO vendas VALUES(default, variavel, null, $3, preco_bebidas.Bebidas * $3, now())
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function vender(character,character varying,integer) line 11 at SQL statement
>   ********** Error **********
>   
>   ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "preco_bebidas"
>   SQL state: 42P01
>   Context: PL/pgSQL function vender(character,character varying,integer) line 11 at SQL statement

A função é a seguinte:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vender(char, varchar(40), int) RETURNS VOID AS $$

DECLARE
    variavel INTEGER;

BEGIN

    IF $1 = 'B' THEN
        SELECT INTO variavel id from Bebidas
        where nome like $2;
        INSERT INTO vendas VALUES(default, variavel, null, $3, Bebidas.preco_bebidas * $3, now());

    END IF;
    IF $1 = 'S' THEN
        SELECT INTO variavel id from Shots
        where nome like $2;
        INSERT INTO vendas VALUES(default, null, variavel, $3, Shots.preco_shots * $3, now());

    END IF;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

O problema não é no ALIAS (AS), ja tentei e não resolveu.
Me ajudem, já estou a horas tentando e não consigo resolver.

Comment: no seu `insert`, isso não faz sentido: `Bebidas.preco_bebidas * $3`, não pode colocar uma referencia para uma tabela e um campo assim, precisaria `select` ali, ou ainda jogar o valor antes em uma variável. O `values` deve ser um valor, variável, ou select

Comment: Você não informou a definição das tabelas envolvidas mas, me parece, a utilização da cláusula FROM do comando UPDATE substituiria este seu SELECT. Consulte a documentação.

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!